# A way to log sql text when inserted

Tags: oracle

I Have the below trigger, the job of this trigger is to track the SQL Query of a developer when inserting on tab1, lets say if the dev executed this query :

> update tab1 set col1 = 1;

the triger should insert that query in the TAB_LOGS.
however I am facing an error 'Exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows'
 on this block

```
select a.SQL_TEXT into V_SQL    
from   v$session s
join   v$sqlarea a on ( a.ADDRESS = s.SQL_ADDRESS )
where  s.OSUSER = V_USERNAME;
```

this is the trigger

```
create or replace trigger TRG_test
after INSERT or update or delete
   ON tab1
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
V_USERNAME VARCHAR2(100);
V_SQL      varchar2(4000);
begin

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') into V_USERNAME  FROM dual;

select a.SQL_TEXT into V_SQL    
from   v$session s
join   v$sqlarea a on ( a.ADDRESS = s.SQL_ADDRESS )
where  s.OSUSER = V_USERNAME;

insert into tab_logs (V_USERNAME,V_SQL);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where  s.OSUSER = V_USERNAME;
```

That would give you every SQL for every session with osuser `V_USERNAME`. There might be more than one such session (in fact, it is pretty common). What you actually want is to audit the SQL issued by *the current session*.

```
select a.SQL_TEXT into V_SQL    
from   v$session s
join   v$sqlarea a on ( a.ADDRESS = s.SQL_ADDRESS )
where  s.AUDSID = userenv('SESSIONID');
```

Comment: it solved the problem for the exact fetch .. but the result of the V$sql is wrong , is it might my query is wrong ?